# Apache POI: comments in empty cells in an empty row

Tags: excel, apache-poi, xssf, hssf

I have a big problem with Apache POI.

```
    A       B       C       D
1   text    text    text    text
2                   comment           
3   text    text    text    text
```

In this example row 2 is empty, C2 has no text, but a comment.

If I want to get row 2, POI will return null.

How can I get a comment from an empty cell in an empty row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fetch arbitrary comments, without going via the Cell directly, you can use [Sheet.gteCellComment(int row, int cell)](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#getCellComment%28int,%20int%29)

From your example, to get the comment in C2, do something like:

```
CellReference ref = new CellReference("C2")
Comment commentC2 = sheet.getCellComment(ref.getRow(), ref.getCol());
```

Comment: Hey :), thank you for this answer. It works for comments, but what can I do, if I have an empty cell with cellstyle only? Is there a solution, too?

Comment: If a cell is explicitly styled, it'll be returned as a cell of type Blank. If it's only implicitly styled, you'll need to fetch the default styling off the row

Comment: unfortunately not...the row has no style and the cell is not blank

Comment: i'm sorry, the problem was that i used a style sheet (from styles and formatting)... the XSSFSheet does'nt read a foregroundcolor from a standard style sheet